# Collapsible Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, collapsable

I try to implement Collapsible toolbar feature in my app.
I followed all instructions - wrapped everything in Coordinator Layout, used AppBarLayout but the Toolbar doesn't collapse on scroll...

My layout code:

```
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.app.chasebank"
       android:id="@+id/main_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       tools:context=".AddItemsActivity">


          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
          </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

          <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_scrollFlags ="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And my Activity code looks like this:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =(CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Buy");
```

I don't understand - why it doesn't collapse and looks like "pinned" on the screen...
Will appreciate any advice/ help!

Answer (score 1):

Put RecyclerView after AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.app.chasebank"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AddItemsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags ="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put recycler View after AppBarLayout and use **  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"** in toolbar instead of app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways".

Comment: Maybe it would be a good choice if you would copy the origin xml and post it inside the answer with your described changes ? So it would be 100% clear what your solution looks like exactly and no misinterpretation possible.